# SAP Report with Assets and Useful Life?

Tags: sap-erp, accounting

I need to create an asset report with columns Asset Number/Class and Useful Life, but there doesn't seem to be anywhere I can get this information.

I read a post instructing to create a query via the transaction code `ARQ0`.

Can you give me clues how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Making a query means that you create a basic report without the need to program anything. You do that with the transaction code SQ01 (with ARQ0 you get right into the user group for asset management). You can read more about queries [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/05/09/sap-query-creation-execution-table-join-logical-database/).

There is a logical database that contains the fields you need, ADA. You will probably have infosets using that logical database that you can choose from. If you want to make your own infoset, the database table containing the asset number and class is ANLA and the useful life is stored in ANLB (beware of double entries). But using a standard logical database is a better choice.

If you want to create a query only you can use, or that you aren't sure about yet, you can use SQVI to create it. If you're happy with it, you can [convert it](http://sapuniversity.eu/how-to-share-an-sqvi-query-in-sap/).

If you want to write the report yourself, you will have to use a JOIN to get all the needed data. Even then it's a better choice to make the query first and copy the JOIN of the query code into your own program.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the transactions `S_ALR_87011964`, `AW01N` ("Parameters" tab of transactional history) and `AS03`("Deprec areas" tab of master data).

[image]

Is this what are you looking for? Maybe there is no need to write new report?